# Xamarin Android Google Maps error in Fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, xamarin

I'm getting an error while displaying maps in a fragment, I've been searching for the solution and Tried several codes but nothing seems to work.

**MainActivity.xml**

[image]

**StackTrace**: {Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment --->
 Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment --->
 Java.Lang.RuntimeException: ***API key not found.***
 ***Check that  
 is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml***

it says API Key not found, but i did declared it in manifest and validated it using http://yougapi.com/tools/google-api-key-checker.php

**AndroidManifest.xml**
[image]

**activity_main.xml**

[image]

PS: Im using android 9.0 physical device for debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure if you have install `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps` package from NuGet.
[image]

And you used Android 9.0 physical device, please make sure your device if have **Google Play services**

I test my demo in the Android 10.0 emulator, it worked as normal.
[image]

Here is my demo. You can test it.

https://github.com/851265601/XAndroidMap

Comment: I am glad to hear that, if the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(Click “✔” in the upper right corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.